# ruby unexpected keyword

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently developing with ruby for the first time.
Can you see why i keep getting the following errors:

```
    /home/apple/Desktop/homework/app/views/specialization/index.html.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

    /home/apple/Desktop/homework/app/views/specialization/index.html.erb:38: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

    Extracted source (around line #36):

31: </tabel>
32: </body>
```

I try to access a database with ruby and read some simple specialization tuples..
This is my page code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>

        <tr>
            <td>Specialization</td>
            <td>Number of applicants</td>
            <td>Applicants</td>
        </tr>

        <% Specialization.all.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
            <td> <%= s.title %> </td>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <td>applicant1</td>
                    <td>applicant2</td>

                </table>
            </td>

        <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button> </td>

        </tr>

        </tr>
        <% end >
</tabel>
</body>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: How 'bout an extra `%` on that end statement? `<% end %>`

Comment: OMG I spent the last hour looking for it! Thank you man...I should take a break now haha

Comment: Also, fix that `</tabel>` over there! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see

```
<% end >
```

should be

```
<% end %>
```

And you shouldn't be selecting the model in the view like this

```
<% Specialization.all.each do |s| %>
```

You should find the specializations in your index action in the controller

```
def index
  @specializations = Specialization.all
end
```

And in the view

```
<% @specializations.each do |s| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a %

```
<% end %>
```